# Value Error Converting the datatype of elements in an array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Im trying to put all matching elements in two different arrays into a singular one. However I'm running into a type error that I'm not entirely sure about.

This is what I initially tried to do:

```
IRS_zips = AGI.zipcode.unique() # np array of type int
medi_zips = df.nppes_provider_zip.unique() # np array of type object
```

In order to find the matching elements I do:

```
like_zips = np.intersect1d(IRS_zips,medi_zips)
```

This throws this error:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Which makes sense, so I check the types of both arrays and attempt to convert them, in this case `medi_zips` is not the right type so I try to convert that one:

```
medi_fixed = medi_zips.astype(int)
```

Which throws the error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'M4K 2'
```

I find this curious, so I look through the data frame for a value that equals `'M4K 2'`, I do find it, and it ends up being the first element of the dataframe and more importantly shows up as a number or in this case a zipcode. Which leads me to think that its an encoding issue maybe? Which im not very strong in.

EDIT:

As requested this is what the output for IRS_zips looks like:

```
array([    0, 35004, 35005, ..., 83127, 83128, 83414])
```

And this is the output array for medi_zips:

```
array(['21502', '60201', '43623', ..., '81656', '56137', '85246'],
      dtype=object)
```

The ideal output would be just a new array with the matched zips, however it is the errors that I listed above

EDIT 2:

This now works:

```
IRS_zips = AGI.zipcode.unique()
IRS_zips = (pd.to_numeric(IRS_zips, errors='coerce')).astype(int)

medi_zips = df.nppes_provider_zip.unique()
medi_int = pd.to_numeric(medi_zips, errors='coerce')
medi_int = (medi_int[~np.isnan(medi_int)]).astype(int)
```

Comment: how about also posting a sample data for readers? also an expected output. :)

Comment: So this particular value cannot be converted to an `int`. Is that what you expected?

Comment: Yes when I checked the type the initial type error made sense

Comment: how about `pd.to_numeric(medi_zips,errors='coerce')` this will convert to float

Comment: Would it make more sense to force the `IRS_zips` to string?  All you want is to match them.  Numeric order isn't important; string lexical order would be just as good.  USA postal codes are numeric, but that's true for many other countries (e.g. Canada).

Comment: @anky_91 that worked, I'm changing it to int, however the 'coerce ' is throwing Nans into the array which I'm looking into

Comment: @SebastianGoslin it will throw NaN wherever you have string values example: `'M4K 2'`

Comment: @anky_91 thats what I'm curious about, I saw the 'M4K 2' initially and figured that it was just an error in the row, so I looked for any rows that had that value as the zip code and it returned one, and the value that was in the zip code was an actual zipcode and not 'M4K 2' which made me think encoding

Comment: @hpaulj I need them as ints as I'm going to be passing them into a function that needs them as ints

Comment: @SebastianGoslin can you check the index which throws NaN and see the values there. it will help you figure out the anomalies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is working for me

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

IRS_zips = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
medi_zips = np.array(['0', '1', '2', '3', '4c'])

medi_int = pd.to_numeric(medi_zips, errors='coerce')

medi_int = medi_int[~np.isnan(medi_int)]

like_zips = np.intersect1d(IRS_zips, medi_int)
```

Comment: Same error `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'M4K 2'`

Comment: That means that some objects in your `medi_zips` are not convertible to int

Comment: `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'` I thought it was because the IRS_zips were string so I converted them to ints as well and now this error

Comment: Woops forgot to use `medi_ints` but now it works! Thank you!